# Exporting blade with image to Excel

Tags: php, excel, laravel-4

Using Laravel Excel I tried to export blade with an image to Excel. The image is coming in Excel but I cannot set its position. Image is displaying at the center of the cell, I need it at the left. I tried margin and width, but that doesn't work. This is my blade:

```
<html>
    <?php $path = public_path(); ?>
    <table> 
    <tr>
        <td align="center" valign="middle" height="50">
            <strong>
                {{$title}}
            </strong>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src="{{$path}}/pieCharts/abc.png" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
</html>
```

This is my code:

```
    App:: make('excel');
    Excel::create($title, function($excel) use ($month_name, $year, $hd) 
    {
        $title = $hd.' '.$month_name.' '.$year;

        $excel->sheet('Pie Chart', function($sheet) use ($title) 
        {
            $sheet->loadView('utilityPieChart')->with('title', $title);
        });    

    })->download('xls');
```

Can we apply position to image?